# Some whites and blues appear either grainy, or with "rainbow" lines

Tags: display, amd-radeon

I've been using my BenQ RL2455HM monitor for several years now and have only recently noticed this effect. I am running Windows 10 version 1803 and use an AMD Radeon 380 series card with 18.7.1 drivers (the most recent).

The display works fine for the most part (in its Standard display mode - not the low-latency mode made specifically for gaming), but I noticed something odd happening in the Windows title bar of my web browser one day. It was displaying this colour:

[image: Purplish colour]

and it looked incredibly noisy/grainy. The rest of the screen looked fine.

Then I started noticing that the Firefox back button started looking odd too, with lines of fluttering rainbow pixels running down it:

[image: Firefox back button]

Switching from using YCbCr 4:4:4 pixel mode in AMD Settings to RGB 4:4:4 seemed to resolve the issue, but the colours don't feel as natural in this mode, even with the full 0-255 RGB range enabled on my monitor.

Is this a problem with my monitor, my drivers, the cable?

Thanks.

Comment: If it only started to happen recently and you didnt change your drivers or related software it's almost certainly a hardware issue. Do you have another monitor to test? That way you could rule out whether it's the monitor or something else. Same goes for the table, do you have or can you borrow another cable from someone else to identify the issue?

Comment: I've tried switching out the cable, no luck there. It almost feels like the monitor's trying to emulate a colour through this effect. Is this something monitors do?

Comment: I suspect it's the monitor but, especially if it only appeared recently, I assume it's a defect. Probably with the monitor's driver board unable to process certain colors/color-ranges/signals/color-modes/...